# Cannot install auto-complete-auctex

Tags: package, auctex

I just installed `auto-complete-auctex` from melpa repository. At package documentation says to enable by putting in my `.init` file the following command

> (require 'auto-complete-auctex)

However, when i launch emacs i get the following error

> Symbol's value as variable is void: ac-modes

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: [ac-modes](https://github.com/auto-complete/auto-complete/blob/master/auto-complete.el#L199) is defined in `auto-complete` package.  Did `package` install `auto-complete`as a dependency as well?

Comment: yes... the package installs `auto-complete` as well